# Format a date by reversing the position of the year, month and days

Tags: date, quasar

The value received from the Date Picker is in the format **"02-06-2020"** (formatted with mask = "DD-MM-YYYY" in q-date).

I need to convert it to **"2020-06-02"** format to send it to the server.

I tried the following, but I get undefined.

Example:

```
let myDate = "02-06-2020";          
console.log(date.formatDate(myDate, "YYYY-MM-DD")) //undefined
```

I would appreciate suggestions for finding a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment js.

```
moment(moment('13-01-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

or

```
date.split("-").reverse().join("-");
```